# How to set my HTML Table progressively with Javascript/AJAX and Java Servlet?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

Hy everyone! I've got a problem developping a little webapp.
The goal is to search for a specific word in files from a stating folder on the server.

To do that, I've implemented a recursive algorithm using java.io.File and a BufferReader.
When I get the results, I had them in a table using a script in my jsp file :

```
// Posting founded files in a table.
var files = response.getElementsByTagName("file");
// -> Creating the results table.
var table = "<table width=\"100%\">\n";

for (var i = 0, c = files.length; i < c; i++) {
// -> Building the number of apparence in each file.
var nb = files[i].getAttribute("nb");
var nbSentence = "";
if (nb == 1) { nbSentence = nb + " time in this file."; }
else { nbSentence = nb + " times in this file."; }

// Building and filling the table. 
if (i % 2 == 0) { table += "<tr class=\"pair\"><td><a href=" + files[i].firstChild.nodeValue + " target=\"_blank\" >"
                + files[i].getAttribute("name") + "</a></td><td>" + nbSentence + "</td></tr>\n"; }
else { table += "<tr class=\"impair\"><td><a href=" + files[i].firstChild.nodeValue + " target=\"_blank\" >"
                + files[i].getAttribute("name") + "</a></td><td>" + nbSentence + "</td></tr>\n"; }
}
table += "</table>\n";
// -> To end the procedure, we had the table to the right div.
document.getElementById("files").innerHTML = table;
```

My problem is that with this code, all of the results are printed in one tim in the target table. I would like to see the results comming one by one, everytime a file is found in the algorithm.

I've tried to change the readystate to "3" in the onreadystatestage function :

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState >= 3 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
    callback(xhr.responseXML);
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("btn").value = "Search";
} else if (xhr.readyState < 3) {
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("btn").value = "Cancel";
}
};
```

But it doesn't change anything.
Does somebody have an idea? How can I send every founded file one by one ? Do I have t do it in the servlet class ?

The for instruction in the servlet class :

```
// If the input word name isn't empty, the algorithm is launched.
if (null != wordToSearch && !"".equals(wordToSearch))
{
lstFiles.clear();
searching(new File(contextPath), wordToSearch);

int n = lstFiles.size();
// Priting a message that indicate how many files have been found with the word to search.
emptyFieldMessage = n + " files has been found containing the word '" + wordToSearch + "'!";
output.append("<message>").append(emptyFieldMessage).append("</message>\n");
output.append("<lstFiles>\n");
// Then, files list with :
// - File path in "name" parameter,
// - Number of apparence of the word in "nb" parameter,
// - Formatted path as the value.
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    output.append("<file name=\"" + lstFiles.get(i) + "\" nb=\"" + lstNbApparence.get(i) + "\" >").append(lstFilesPath.get(i)).append("</file>\n");
}
output.append("</lstFiles>\n");
}
```

To be more complet, the whole script code :

```
<script>
// Creating xhr variable.
var xhr = null;

// Creating the "Search" button function.
function request(callback) {

   // "Cancel" button case.
   if (xhr && xhr.readyState != 0)
   {
       xhr.abort();
   }
   // "Search" button case.
   else
   {
       // Calling the good function from external file.
       xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

       // Callback and loading icon management.
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState >= 3 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            callback(xhr.responseXML);
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("btn").value = "Search";
        } else if (xhr.readyState < 3) {
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("btn").value = "Cancel";
        }
      };

      // Calling the Servlet in charge of the recursion algorithm.
      var input = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("wordName").value);
      xhr.open("GET", "/webApp_Search_Merge/ActionServlet?wordName=" + input, true);
      xhr.send(null);
      }
}

// Creating the reponse function.
function readData(response) {

if (null != response)
{
    // Posting the message include in the XML file sending back by the Servlet.
    var message = response.getElementsByTagName("message");
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

    // Posting founded files in a table.
    var files = response.getElementsByTagName("file");
    // -> Creating the results table.
    var table = "<table width=\"100%\">\n";

    for (var i = 0, c = files.length; i < c; i++) {
        // -> Building the number of apparence in each file.
        var nb = files[i].getAttribute("nb");
        var nbSentence = "";
        if (nb == 1) { nbSentence = nb + " time in this file."; }
        else { nbSentence = nb + " times in this file."; }

        // Building and filling the table. 
        if (i % 2 == 0) { table += "<tr class=\"pair\"><td><a href=" + files[i].firstChild.nodeValue + " target=\"_blank\" >"
            + files[i].getAttribute("name") + "</a></td><td>" + nbSentence + "</td></tr>\n"; }
        else { table += "<tr class=\"impair\"><td><a href=" + files[i].firstChild.nodeValue + " target=\"_blank\" >"
            + files[i].getAttribute("name") + "</a></td><td>" + nbSentence + "</td></tr>\n"; }
    }
    table += "</table>\n";
    // -> To end the procedure, we had the table to the right div.
    document.getElementById("files").innerHTML = table;
}
```

}

Thanks by advance for your help, Thomas.

Comment: I did not understand the question. Be clear and concise, please. Also, should post your AJAX call code

Comment: Hy, sorry about that. I posted the whole script above.

Now, what I want, is to see the results comming one by one in the table, not in one time.
Everytime I found a file in the servlet algorithm, I would like to post it in the table and not waiting for the whole algorithm to be done.

I hope this is clearer and thanks for your help by the way. Thomas.

Comment: Sorry to answering so late, here was launchtime. If I understood what you want to do, your goal it's to ask server to retrieve some data from a file. When server gets the request, it goes to the specified file, checks all lines in that file and found 2000 lines, for example. Then, you want to retrieve 1 response for each line to load them 1 by 1 and "simulate" as if your table is filling 1 by 1. I don't know if you found the error on what you want, if its this what you want to achieve, but you can't say to server to retrieve 2000 responses. You will overload it => next comment for more info.

Comment: With some luck, even if you try to simulate that, you will get the data instantly. What you have to do, is to retrieve data into the AJAX call, even if it is instantly processed, and send it to a function that has an interval, to load your data in your table after X milliseconds. I can try to give you an answer if you want.

Comment: It is really close from what I'm triying to do.
I'm not triying to get the 2000 lines back. I'm checking every files from a starting folder. In those files, I do read every line and check if the word that I want is in it.
If it's true, then I had the file to the final list, and it's that list (of files, not lines) that I send to the page.

Then, I post the result in the table. If I found 35 files, I'd like them to be sent and posted one by one and not when all of the files have been checked.

If there's no other way than simulating it, then go for it, I'd like yr answer! Thanks for your time.

Comment: You are welcome! We are here to help. I will ask you now if you are using jQuery or you were thinking about using it. That's to have a base where I can start doing an example. Also, I need what kind of data do you recieve, just an example like if you retrieve a list of objects or whatever (i.e.) `[{id: 1, name: "John", tax: 25.00}...]` to have an example where I can start doing a demo.

Comment: I didn't particulary planed to use jQuery, but why not...

About the data, it is pretty simple, I build an xml file like this :
<message>35 files has been found containing the word 'config'!"</message>
<lstFiles>
<file name = C:\\test.xml nb = 3>test.xml</file>
...
</lstFiles>

Where nb is the number of time I've found the word in the file.

Hope it's clear.

Comment: Seems like you are returning an XML to your webpage then. I will try to build a demo and you report if it works for you.

Comment: Perfect, I wait for your demo. Thanxs a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set up a working demo, but with no results. I was also searching why I can't find the way to "sleep" a `function` and re-execute after 1000 milliseconds or whatever you want. Already found an answer to that, but I think it's not really what did you expected:

> A sleep function will kill the browser and possibly the machine.
>   Javascript is single threaded, so the browser will block while this
>   executes, and the loop itself will just take up a lot of CPU. I’ve
>   heard of some libraries that actually do sleep correctly in an
>   asynchronous manner, but I can’t remember the name right now.
>
> ---
>
> This is a very bad idea. JavaScript is single threaded so while that
>   for loop is running nothing else can execute (js timers, browser
>   events, even the UI in most browsers). Try to sleep for 5 or more
>   seconds and the browser will even warn the user that a script is
>   running slowly.
>
> Just use setTimeout.

Also speaks about a sleep function into **[Native Javascript](http://www.neilmix.com/narrativejs/doc/index.html)**. It seems that it's like a framework or something like that. You can download it and try it at your own. I can't say anything about this because I've never tested, it's just what I found on internet.

I'm sorry to give you bad news.

Comment: Hy DaGLiMiOuX and thank you so much for your help and your time. It's ok, even if it would have been great to manage doing it, it's not the most important part of my application.

Thanks a lot again for your help.